# Handling a mixture of encrypted and unencrypted data in a column

Tags: postgresql, encryption

i was trying to used encryption on my Postgres site, but then again I came a cross some issues about on "ERROR: decrypt error: Data not a multiple of block size". I'm afraid I might have a problem to this issues in the near future. I noticed that when I save a text on the db which was not encrypted the errors occurs. I'll be using some codeigniter on my site, but the problem since we are seven on the team, probably someone will accidentally not encrypted and save on the databased. And these issues will occur again I don't know what to do when that situation comes.

MY option was to delete manually on the database which data was not encrypted, but the problem is when that happens, what if db data was around 60,000 and if we try to check which part were going to delete will take us time to determine which was not encrypted. Please advice sorry for wrong grammar.

Using PostgreSQL 9.3.5

My QUERY Code

```
INSERT INTO table (text) VALUES (encrypt('my encrypt text here','secretkey','aes'));
```

When displaying a query.

```
SELECT decrypt(text,'secretkey','aes') from table
```

But when someone accidentally insert some table without "encrypt" , ERROR: decrypt error: Data not a multiple of block size.Anybody can enlighten me.

Comment: You have left out all the important bits, like *the code you use*, your PostgreSQL version, etc.

Comment: in what way? please enlighten me

Comment: The SQL that produces the error. The client-side code, if relevant. The exact PostgreSQL server version. The input values for the SQL. (You are not using "Postgre 1.18" - that might be the PgAdmin-III version, though. Try `SELECT version()` for the PostgreSQL version).

Comment: these is the result "PostgreSQL 9.3.5, compiled by Visual C++ build 1600, 32-bit" would these be a stable version?i have edit my questions as well.please advise

Comment: Aah, so the problem is with unencrypted data in an otherwise encrypted column. There's no simple solution to that, because there's no prefix on encrypted data to say "this is encrypted".

Comment: yes, thats what i'm afraid of

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61323/discussion-between-boyee-and-craig-ringer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's now clear that the problem you're facing is how to identify unencrypted or corrupt values in a column of text that's otherwise encrypted.

There's no way to tell the difference between "corrupt", "encrypted with a different key to what I tried to use" and "not encrypted" because there's no marker that says "this is encrypted". This isn't a PostgreSQL thing, it's how most cryptographic algorithms work, and it's by design (on purpose).

All you can do is try to decrypt it with a key and see if that works. Even that is far from reliable, since *values may appear to decrypt "correctly" with a wrong key, and just produce garbage*. e.g.

```
regress=> SELECT encrypt(BYTEA '\xdeadbeef', 'dummykey', 'aes');
              encrypt               
------------------------------------
 \x0716fe8b280863ebf4b69b59a060c176
(1 row)

regress=> SELECT decrypt(BYTEA '\x0716fe8b280863ebf4b69b59a060c176', 'dummykey', 'aes');
  decrypt   
------------
 \xdeadbeef
(1 row)

regress=> SELECT decrypt(BYTEA '\x0716fe8b280863ebf4b69b59a060c176', 'wrong', 'aes');
              decrypt               
------------------------------------
 \xd03d4f275edf1fe058c11207527416f4
(1 row)
```

If you know you have the right key and just want to tell the difference between unencrypted and encrypted data, PL/PgSQL's exception handling is suitable, as it's not very likely that unencrypted text will decrypt as valid aes. So something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION try_decrypt(cyphertext bytea, secretkey bytea, algo text)
RETURNS bool
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
  PERFORM decrypt(cyphertext, secretkey, algo);
  RETURN true;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN external_routine_invocation_exception THEN
    RETURN false;
END;
$$;
```

If you want to change the above so it returns the cyphertext unchanged if it can't decrypt it, or returns null, that's trivial to do.